# Excel VBA Copy/Paste Range to the next available cell in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range, paste

What I want to do: Filter on an array, then copy the filtered data onto a different workbook. Then copy that data that was just pasted onto another worksheet in the same workbook, but this time below existing data.

My thinking: The code I used below was used to help me copy and paste from one workbook to another workbook and worked perfectly,

```
wb.Sheets("2014 Current Week").Range("C2:CC10000").Copy nwb.Sheets("2014 YTD").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

but it seems it does not work the same way if I want to copy in the same workbook. Any help would be appreciated. THANKS!

```
Dim wb as workbook
Dim strs As String
Dim str As String
Dim nwb as workbook


Set wb = ThisWorkbook

strs = wb.Sheets("Macros").Range("H5") 'the 2014 address can be found in full in cell H5 in the Macros tab

set nwb = Workbooks.Open(strs) 'address of new workbook and opens it

With ActiveSheet

.AutofilterMode = False
'Filter this and that here'

End With



 nwb.Sheets("ALL DATA").Range("A1:CA100000").Copy wb.Sheets("2014 Current Week").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp) 
'this one works, and copies exactly as I want into the 2014 Current Week tab

 wb.Sheets("2014 Current Week").Range("C2:CC10000").Copy wb.Sheets("2014 YTD").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 
'this one doesn't work, and does not copy or paste at all from that 2014 Current Week into the 2014 YTD tab of the same workbook
```

Comment: `does not work` = not helpful description.  What does the current code do and how is that different from what you want?  There should be no difference if you're copying between workbooks, worksheets, or ranges on the same sheet.  The issue likely has to do with the specifics of what's on these worksheets, but again a better description of the problem is needed.  Please [edit] that detail into your question.

Comment: Thanks Byron, I edited my question to hopefully explain more of my problem. In addition to the code above, I also tried to copy the data directly from the new workbook into the 2014 YTD tab using this,

nwb.Sheets("ALL DATA").Range("A1:CA100000").Copy wb.Sheets("2014 YTD").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

which is basically the same as the code that works but this one still does not work.

Comment: Code looks good.  That means the issue is specific to your sheets and data.  The best way to proceed is thorough debugging.  You would do well to create a `Range` for both the source and target so that you can see what they contain.  Once you have the variables, you can add a breakpoint, and step through the code to see what it is doing.  Does your `Range` on `2014 Current Week` have any data in it?  Are you sure you want column C on that sheet?  Do you also want such a large block of data?  Is sheet `2014 YTD` where you expect it to go?  There is something simple because your code looks good.

Comment: There are only labels in row 1 in the 2014 Current Week tab, no other data. The layouts of the Current Week and YTD tabs are the same, the only difference is that YTD has existing data. The block of data varies and so the large block is my easiest way of being dynamic to that variation. The data should be pasting into both of the tabs if the code above worked properly, but as of now it is only pasting into the Current Week tab.

Comment: It was just as you said Byron, something simple... apparently there was some data in the YTD tab column C, very far below any of the existing data that I saw. SO, the code was pasting all the new data under this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good and should not have any issues.  Since it seems to not be working, you need to look at the actual `Worksheets` and data involved.

You are using `End` to find the last row of data.  Given this, it is worth testing this yourself.  Go to the last row of the `Worksheet` in column `C` and hit <kbd>CTRL + UP</kbd>.  This will show you where the data is going to be pasted.

Based on your description this last row is the issue.  Since there was some stray data that was affecting `End`.

Comment: Yeah, I found data that was not supposed to be there in column C. This was throwing off where the actual data was supposed to be pasted.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code and it works fine. It pastes the data correctly. Check the names of your sheets.

Comment: I've even tried renaming my sheets... I guess it may be something deeper within the workbook.